# Wildcard for paths in CSS selector

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to use CSS selectors to identify elements. For correct identification, I use a combination of path and attribute based selectors.

Example:

```
div[attribute='test'] > div > div > div > span[attribute='test']
```

Now, in general, only the first and the last element are relevant for correct identification. The path of `> div > div > div >` (can also be much longer) is not that needed and might also be subject to change.

So my question is: Can I use some wildcard for the exact path here to make the selection more flexible?

Like:

```
div[attribute='test'] <wildcard> span[attribute='test']
```

And if not, can this be achieved by other techniques like XPath?

Comment: Oh, I think this can be done just using a whitespace?

Comment: Maybe something like this with XPath: `//div[@attribute='test']//span[@attribute='test']` or with CSS: `div[attribute='test'] * span[attribute='test']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a specific chain of child combinators, you can just use a space (formally known as a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)):

> The **descendant combinator** — typically represented by a single space (" ") character — combines two selectors such that elements matched by the second selector are selected if they have an ancestor (parent, parent's parent, parent's parent's parent, etc.) element matching the first selector.

```
div[attribute='test'] span[attribute='test'] {
   
}
```

This selector selects all `<span attribute="test">` elements that are descendants of a `<div attribute="test">` element, regardless of how deeply nested the span is within the div.

Comment: Perfect. Seems like I should have read the documentation more carefully, before asking that question!